# CoreData iOS crash: _coordinator_you_never_successfully_opened_the_database_missing_directory

Tags: ios, core-data

I receive a lot of crashes with in the stacktrace "_coordinator_you_never_successfully_opened_the_database_missing_directory" on the main thread. This is reported in Crashlytics as "This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (device locked). It cannot perform a save operation."

- is "..._missing_directory" the same as description as Crashlytics is giving ?
- what could be the cause ?
- how should I solve this ?

```
@objc class PersistenceController : NSObject {

    @objc static let shared = PersistenceController()

    fileprivate var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel?
    fileprivate var privateObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?
    fileprivate var name: String = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
    fileprivate var storeLocation: NSURL?

    @objc var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?
    @objc var databasePath: String {
        if let storeLocation = self.storeLocation, let storeLocationPath = storeLocation.path {
            return storeLocationPath
        }
        return "Could not find database path"
    }

    @objc func initializeCoreDataModel(name: String?) -> Bool {

        if let safeName = name {
            self.name = safeName
        }

        // Check if a context alreay exsist
        if (self.managedObjectContext != nil) {
            print("Context already exists, no need to create another")
            return true
        }

        // Fetch the Core Data store
        if let modelUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: self.name + "Datamodel", withExtension: "momd") {

            // Create a model from the store
            if let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelUrl) {

                self.managedObjectModel = mom

                // Create the object contexts
                let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom)

                // Create MainQueue
                self.managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)

                // Create PrivateQueue
                self.privateObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
                self.privateObjectContext?.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator

                // Set MainQueue's parent to PrivateQueue - Now we have Persistent Store Coord => Private => Main
                self.managedObjectContext?.parent = self.privateObjectContext

                // Create the Persistent Store
                if let storeURL = self.storeURL() {

                    if let persistentStoreCoordinator = self.privateObjectContext?.persistentStoreCoordinator {

                        self.storeLocation = storeURL

                        let options: [String : Any] = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
                                                       NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey: FileProtectionType.none,
                                                       NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]

                        do {
                            try persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: self.storeLocation as URL?, options: options)
                            return true
                        } catch {
                            CrashlyticsManager.shared.logCoreDataError(error: error as NSError)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Could not create document url")
                }

            } else {
                print("Could not create model from core data store")
            }

        } else {
            print("Could not find core data store")
        }

        return false
    }

    @objc func save() {

        guard let privateContext = self.privateObjectContext, let managedContext = self.managedObjectContext else {
            return
        }

        if (!privateContext.hasChanges && !managedContext.hasChanges) {
            return
        }

        if !UIApplication.shared.isProtectedDataAvailable {
            let userInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "isProtectedDataAvailable = false, cannot save()", "MainThread": Thread.isMainThread ? "true" : "false"]
            let nsError = NSError(domain: "CoreData", code: 1001, userInfo: userInfo)
            CrashlyticsManager.shared.logCoreDataError(error: nsError)
            return
        }

        managedContext.performAndWait({
            do {
                try managedContext.save()

                privateContext.perform({
                    do {
                        try privateContext.save()
                    } catch {
                        CrashlyticsManager.shared.logCoreDataError(error: error as NSError)
                    }
                })
            } catch {
                CrashlyticsManager.shared.logCoreDataError(error: error as NSError)
            }
        })
    }

    @objc func detachLocalDatabase() {

        save()

        if let privateObjectContext = self.privateObjectContext {
            privateObjectContext.reset()
        }

        if let context = self.privateObjectContext, let coordinator = context.persistentStoreCoordinator {
            for store in coordinator.persistentStores {
                do {
                    try coordinator.remove(store)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }

        managedObjectModel = nil
        managedObjectContext = nil
        privateObjectContext = nil
    }

    @objc func attachLocalDatabase() -> Bool {
        return initializeCoreDataModel(name: "PasNL")
    }

    static func clearDatabase() {
        Coupon.deleteAll()
        CardStatus.deleteAll()
        Message.deleteAll()
        Transaction.deleteAll()
        Setting.deleteAll()
    }
}

private extension PersistenceController {

    func storeURL() -> NSURL? {

        let applicationSupportDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.applicationSupportDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let applicationPath = (applicationSupportDirectoryPath as NSString).appendingPathComponent(self.name)
        let storePath = (applicationPath as NSString).appendingPathComponent("\(self.name).db")

        let fileExists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: storePath)
        if !fileExists {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: applicationPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }

        return NSURL(fileURLWithPath: storePath)
    }
}
```

Comment: nobody can advise ? no reponse yet...

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: No solution found for this issue. I however had the impression that there was some database action (query or save operation) before the persistentStoreCoordinator was fully initialized...